# Run Batch File That Stops Process at Specified Time

Tags: batch-file, minecraft

I'm running a batch file to start a Minecraft server. Here is the following script:

```
@echo off
"%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.4.7-R1.0.jar
pause
```

It just occurred to me that perhaps its possible for the batch file to automatically stop the process on a specified time of day, but not through a countdown of any sort.

In addition, I had hoped that it can write the following lines in the command prompt:

- say Server is closing in 15 minutes (1:45am)
- say Server is closing in 10 minutes (1:50am)
- say Server is closing in 5 minutes (1:55am)
- say Server is closing, goodbye. (2:00am)
- stop (2:00am)

If this is not possible, any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: use a task scheduler ...

Comment: It is probably possible, but has a lot of disadvantages if you really want to do this from a batch file. Using an [in-game plugin](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/auto-shutdown/) is the best solution. Otherwise AutoHotkey or Powershell would be easier.

Comment: What you're asking is possible. Just loop a ping / goto with a check on the time. At 01:45, 01:50 and 01:55 echo warnings.  Then at 02:00 kill Java.exe using wmic, something like `wmic process where name="java.exe" delete`.  I won't be at a Windows computer until Monday.  If this question is still unanswered by then, I'll show you what I've got in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cmd /c "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.4.7-R1.0.jar

:waitloop
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%I in ("%time%") do (
    if "%%I"==" 1" (
        if "%%J"=="45" (
            echo ! Server is closing in 15 minutes.
        ) else if "%%J"=="50" (
            echo ! Server is closing in 10 minutes.
        ) else if "%%J"=="55" (
            echo ! Server is closing in 5 minutes.
        )
    ) else if "%%I"==" 2" (
        echo ! Toodloo.
        wmic process where name="java.exe" delete >NUL 2>NUL
        goto :EOF
    )
    set /a secs=60 - %%K + 1
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n !secs! >NUL
)
goto waitloop
```